# When NSDictionary is added to array, it replaces the previous dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, plist, file-writing, nsdocumentdirectory

**UPDATE: Figured out some stuff and changed code.**

When I add my `NSDictionary` to my array it suddenly replaces the previous dictionary I added last time. I don't know why this is happening. I am using a plist as data storage.

I get a error message like this:

> Thread 1:Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Init

```
-(id)init{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){
        dbArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Adding a new item.

```
-(void)addNewItem:(NSString *)aString
{
    // Creates a mutable dictionary with a anonymous string under the NAME key.
    NSDictionary *newString = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:aString,@"name", nil];

    // Adds the new string to empty dbArray.
    [dbArray addObject:(newString)];
    NSLog(@"[add]:Added anonymous string to dbArray, under name key.");

    // Writes the current dbArray (with the dict) to plist and releases retain counts.
    [self writeItem];
    [newString release];
}
```

My method to view my data.

```
-(void)viewData
{
    // View data from the created plist file in the Documents directory.

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *finalPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:finalPath]) {
        self.dbArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
    }
    else {
        self.dbArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
}
```

Comment: You write to file new array all the time. Mb you should remove `self.dbArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
`. You will append your array and rewrite it properly.

Comment: maybe your `addNewItem` method is not just adding. It looks like you are allocating and initializing a new array before adding the new value to it. This will give a new array with only the new value.

Comment: @RomanTemchenko I have tried removing the `self.dbArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` and when I do that it won't save the dictionary to the array and plist.

Comment: @Ravin455 check whether `dbArray` exists in `addNewItem:`. Do you call `viewData` before `addNewItem:`?

Comment: @RomanTemchenko Yes I do call `viewData` before `addNewItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead this

```
self.dbArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

use this

```
if( nil == self.dbArray ) {
  self.dbArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

**UPDATE:** (based on provided code)

- you're using different instances of DataObject class for displaying & saving data. Your content is over-written, because you don't load data from file during initialization of each instance; to fix that fast, you need to implement init method of your DataObject class as below:

> ```
> - (id)init{
>     self = [super init];
>     if(self){
>       [self viewData];
>     }
>     return self;
> }
> ```

the following code from viewDidLoad of ViewController class will crash your application very often:

> ```
> db = [[DataObject alloc] init];
> [db viewData];
> [db release];
>
> array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[db dbArray]];
> ```

replace it with

```
db = [[DataObject alloc] init];
[db viewData];

array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[db dbArray]];
```

call `[db release]` only in dealloc implementation

- another problem, that you'll probably arise - is updated data is not displayed when you're back to the main screen; to fix that add the following method implementation to your ViewController.m file:

> ```
> - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
> {
>   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
>
>   [db viewData];
>   self.array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: db.dbArray];
>   [self.tableView reloadData];
> }
> ```

also in AddView.m replace the following code

```
// Dismiss view and reload tableview.
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[vc release];
```

with

```
// Dismiss view and reload tableview.
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Just as advise: see more information about using delegates and passing object instances & copies between objects.

Comment: if it still replaces it, do you override a your getter/setter for dbArray property?

Comment: Set NSZombieEnabled to YES and determine what object releasing causes this crash, otherwise - it's just guessing

Comment: `*** -[DataObject dbArray]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a5f4e0` This is what i get when I turned NSZombieEnabled to YES, but this is from another controller thats receiving the message from my NSObject. I have only allocated it once in my NSObject using the `-(id)init` method, otherwise I retained it in my .h file of the NSObject.

Comment: I have my view controller which has this line: `array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[db dbArray]];` I have declared `db` as DataObject (the NSObject).

Comment: i'm afraid, i need to have a look at whole project to be able to help you

Comment: if you had to look at my whole project where would you start then? I only have my view controller and my object so it's not much. It's just a simple app that manages data.

Comment: so just put it somewhere on dropbox, so i can download it and view through

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating a new Array:

```
self.dbArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You should create the dbArray on the `viewDidLoad` or on the init of your `UIViewController` (I am assuming you are using this on an `UIViewController`)

inside your DataObject do the following:

```
  -(id)init{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){
      self.dbArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   }
   return self;
  }
```

Comment: No I am not using `UIViewController`, instead I am using a `NSObject`. So instead of `viewDidLoad` what can I use?

Comment: @Denis gave you answer, but I don't like using "Ifs" when you don't need them. I would override your default `init` method, and would add the allocation there.

Comment: You mean in my `viewData` I should replace `self.dbArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];` with `self.dbArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];`

Comment: No, when you allocated your NSObject, you do something like: `MyObject *myObject=[MyObject alloc] init]` you should override your `init` method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5776/discussion-between-ravin455-and-jacky-boy)